# Not able to display image from loopback server

Tags: ionic-framework

I am able to access the image in the browser from loopback server, But the images is not displaying in the page by using same link.

`<img src="192.168.1.11:3000/api/Pictures/Images/download/1559303030243.jpg">`

[image]

Comment: Try with "http://" at the beginning of the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all it was needed was Http: in front of the URL